# ¿Como recuperar todos los archivos GridFs en MongoDB?

Tags: c#, nodejs, mongodb, mongoose, meteor

He guardado archivos en Mongodb usando GridFs y C# pero ahora necesito recuperar TODOS los archivos que he guardado en mi base y almacenarlos en una carpeta.
Espero puedan asesorarme un poco. Gracias

Este es el Codigo como guardo mis archivos

```
var connectionString = "mongodb://localhost";
var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
var server = client.GetServer();
var database = server.GetDatabase("data");
var gridFs = new MongoGridFs(database);

//Este es el archivo que subo a la Base
string ruta = "C:\\files\\rasta.jpeg";

//Esta parte hace el proceso de carga
      using (var file = File.OpenRead(ruta))
    {
        id = gridFs.AddFile(file, rute);                            
    }
```

Asi me muestra los archivos mi Robomongo
[image: Robomongo]

Lo que necesito es recuperar todos los archivos que he guardado en mi Base y almacenarlo en mi carpeta "C:/"

Como recupero un archivo???
Obtengo el id del ultimo archivo guardado y lo almaceno en un MemoryStream

```
     using (var file = gridFs.GetFile(id))
        {
            var buffer = new byte[file.Length];
            string sd = file.Read(buffer, 0, (int)file.Length).ToString();
            MemoryStream MS = new MemoryStream(buffer);
        }
```

Una vez obtenido el MemoryStream es sencillo guardar mi archivo en mi directorio, lo que se me complica es obtener TODOS los archivos guardados en la base de datos y guardarlos en mi Carpeta.

En la parte Inferior escribo la manera en que solucione mi problema

Comment: ¿Solo quieres obtener la ruta y copiarlos a otra parte?

Comment: La ruta no es necesario, solo generar el archivo y guardarlo en una carpeta especifica

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aqui, en la documentación oficial de `MongoDB` no existe ningun metodo que retorne todos los archivos de una vez [documentación](http://api.mongodb.com/csharp/current/html/N_MongoDB_Driver_GridFS.htm). Sin embargo, si puedes guardar esas informaciones en una tabla puedes ocupar esta solucion :

Dentro de tu proyecto `c#` debes crear una clase del tipo de objeto que guardas en tu base de datos. Supongamos que tu objeto tiene

Id, Nombre, Apellido, imagen y tu tabla se llama Persona.

Debes crear una clase llamada Persona con los atributos antes mencionados, luego creas.

```
var client = new MongoClient();
var db = client.GetDataBase("TuDB");
var coleccion = db.GetCollection<Persona>("Persona");

var objetos = coleccion.Select(p => p).ToListAsync().Result;
foreach (var objeto in objetos)
{
    Console.WriteLine(" Id: " + objeto.Id);
}
```

**EDIT**

Creo que `var objetos = coleccion.Select(p => p).ToListAsync().Result;` no es necesario en este caso cuando no necesitas filtrar por algun campo en especial de tu tabla. Si necesitas todos y sin filtro puedes ejecutar `db.GetCollection<Persona>("Persona.Id");` Por lo tanto podria ser asi :

```
var coleccion = db.GetCollection<Persona>("Persona");
foreach (var objeto in collecion)
{
    Console.WriteLine(" Id: " + objeto.Id);
}
```

Aqui vas a tener todas las id, todas las ruta de las imagenes o lo que quieras de tu objeto y puedes guardarlas dentro de la carpeta que desees. No dejo el codigo de guardarlas ya que tu mismo nombraste que se te hacia facil poder guardar con la id el objeto, dentro del foreach deberias guardar las imagenes en tu carpeta local.

Para filtrar si es que lo necesitas puede ser :

```
coleccion.Find(p => p.Nombre == 'Ejemplo').Limit(5).ToListAsync().Result;
```

***Nota :***

Para crear la clase de forma rapida copia el formato JSON que obtienes de tu MongoDB, elimina las palabras `ObjectId`, `ISODate` y luego en Visual Studio en la pestaña `Edit->Paste Special->Paste JSON As Classes` y crea tu clase, luego debes cambiar obviamente el nombre de la clase que se genera y las `id` que tengas las creara como `string`, debes cambiarlas a `ObjectId` y agregar la dependiencia de `MongoDB ObjectId`

Answer (score 2):

> Esta es la manera en que pude resolver mi problema, espero que les sea
>   útil.

`GridFs`, permite almacenar archivos de gran volumen en nuestra base de datos `Mongo` (música,videos, etc) estos archivos se particionan en arreglos de 16 MB, automáticamente crea dos `Collection` (tablas) *fs.files* y *fs.chunks*.

Para conectar `Mongodb` con `C#`, es necesario un *Driver* el cual puede ser descargado desde el `Nuget Package` de `C#` `Mongocsharpdriver` y agregar sus ensamblados.

```
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using MongoDB.Driver.Builders;
using MongoDB.Driver.GridFS;
using MongoDB.Driver.Linq;
```

¿Cómo subo archivos a la base de datos `MongoDB`?

```
//Datos del Servidor
var connectionString = "mongodb://localhost";
var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
var server = client.GetServer();
var database = server.GetDatabase("data");
var gridFs = new MongoGridFs(database);

//Este es el archivo que subo a la Base
string ruta = "C:\\files\\foto.jpeg";

//Esta parte hace el proceso de carga
  using (var file = File.OpenRead(ruta))
{
    id = gridFs.AddFile(file, rute);                            
}
```

¿Cómo recupero el archivo que se ha cargado?

```
 using (var file = gridFs.GetFile(id))
    {
        var buffer = new byte[file.Length];
        string sd = file.Read(buffer, 0, (int)file.Length).ToString();
        MemoryStream MS = new MemoryStream(buffer);
        pictureBox.Image = Image.FromStream(MS); //Mostrar la Fotografia
    }
```

¿Cómo recupero todos los archivos que se han cargado?

```
protected static IMongoClient cliente = new MongoClient();
protected static IMongoDatabase data = cliente.GetDatabase("database");
var collection = data.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("fs.files");
var filtro = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Empty;
var cursor = collection.Find(filtro);
var listado = cursor.ToList();
foreach (var item in listado)
   {
     string idfile = item["_id"].ToString();
     using (var file = gridFs.GetFile(ObjectId.Parse(idfile)))
       {
         var buffer = new byte[file.Length];
         string sd = file.Read(buffer, 0, (int)file.Length).ToString();
         //Guardo todos los archivos subidos a la base en la carpeta Fotografias
         FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\Fotografias\" + idfile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
         fs.Write(buffer, 0, (int)file.Length);
          fs.Close();
        }
   }
```

Comment: Lo bueno es que ocupaste o al menos te guio mi respuesta. En la mia traigo la lista de forma asincrona por resultados variados!

Comment: Asi es amigo @sioesi muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo para responder, te he otorgado la recompensa. Saludos

Comment: Un saludo amigo @Rastalovely que bueno poder haberte ayudado!